# triggering js function when any element is clicked on the webpage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am writing a chrome extension where i want to pass the element clicked on the webpage to be passed into a js function which will calculate the css selector.

i am not able to figure out how to to trigger the js function when any element is clicked on the webpage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an event listener in your content script that checks for user clicks, capture the target element, and then use chrome.runtime.sendMessage to send the data to your background page or other target destination.

content.js

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    var attributes = Array.prototype.slice.call(target.attributes).map(function(i)    {
        return [String(i.name)+": "+String(i.value)]
    })

    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({method:"captureElement",data:attributes});   
},true)
```

background.js

```
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
   // alert(changeInfo.url);
   chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {"file": "content.js"});
});

var container = []
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message){
  if(message.method == "captureElement"){
    container.push(message.data)
    alert(message.data)
  }
})
```

manifest.json

```
 {
 "name": "stack practice",
 "version": "1.0",
 "description": " content script and background page communication",

 "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]

  },

   "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["content.js"]
 }],
  "permissions": [
    "http://*/",
     "contextMenus",
     "activeTab"
],
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Comment: i tried but its not working. i added the files as you wrote.

Comment: i have just created a manifest file and included these two files you wrote. but its not working.

Comment: these are not complete files, just code snippets illustrating how a content script can interact with the user's active tab in the browser and then relay specific data back to your program.  You also need to execute the content script.

Comment: really sorry for troubling you. but i am just beginner may you please explain me what to do for this to work.

Comment: i tried with the edited code. but still not working.
i am posting my manifest file. may you please explain how it will work.
@nick

Comment: ` {
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "icons": { "16": "icons/icon.png",
             "48": "icons/icon.png",
            "128": "icons/icon.png" },
  "name": " Select",
  "description": "to give element clicked on a webpage.",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "19": "icons/icon.png",
      "38": "icons/icon.png"
    },
 "content_scripts": [{"js" : ["content.js"]}],
    "default_title": "select"
  }
}
`

Comment: I pasted working code.  This is as simple as I can make it.  upload it to chrome and test it out.  it simply alerts the user of the attributes of the html element  that they clicked on.

Comment: Thank you so much  @nick :)

Comment: the question might sound silly but in background.js why there are no semicolon after the var line and onMessage,addListener ? @nick

Comment: This will start the listener on tab activation, but what about if the user refreshes the tab, or starts a new window?

Comment: @nick this extension keeps running all the time. i tried making a a panel at devtool_page but i am not able to start or stop it from there. i created a button  there but not able to make it work only when that button is clicked.
Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use event parameter target property, like this:

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    console.log(e.target);
});
```

See full description at [MDN: Event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function and call it when clicked any element, pass the element id as an argument and after getting id of the element you can do whatever you want.

Simple code when clicked inside a div will give an alert message-

The event handler can be bound to any `<div>`:

```
<div id="target">
Click here
</div>
<div id="other">
Click here
</div>

$( "#target" ).click(function() {
alert( "target div is called." );
});
```