# how to execute content script function just once every time i click button from devtool page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

i have been working on a chrome extension and with the help of this post [triggering javascript function on click and getting element details which is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35620119/triggering-js-function-when-any-element-is-clicked-on-the-webpage), i am getting the element details clicked on but the problem is this extension keep on running ! i want to trigger it just once every time i click a button from devtools page of my chrome extension. how to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to implement a `removeEventListener` after your event implementation

```
document.getElementById("ID").removeEventListener("click", myFunction);
```

You can use this SO post as a referrence ([JavaScript: remove event listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402287/javascript-remove-event-listener))

Comment: Thank you for the help @SwagBomb